# Tidy.NET and html entities

Tags: c#, .net, html-entities, tidy

When I try to cleanup HTML-code with Tidy.NET it broke HTML-entities like `&#x65;` `&#64;` or `&#x73;` and make HTML unreadable. I trying different settings, but it all variants was unsuccessful.

Anybody know how to solve this problem? May be hotfix exists?

Edit 1:
I use this configuration of Tidy

```
Tidy doc = new Tidy();
doc.Options.DocType = DocType.User;
doc.Options.Xhtml = true;
doc.Options.WrapScriptlets = true;
doc.Options.LogicalEmphasis = true;
doc.Options.DropFontTags = true;
doc.Options.DropEmptyParas = true;
doc.Options.QuoteAmpersand = true;
doc.Options.TidyMark = false;
doc.Options.MakeClean = true;
doc.Options.IndentContent = true;
doc.Options.SmartIndent = true;
doc.Options.Spaces = 0;
doc.Options.WrapLen = 0;
doc.Options.CharEncoding = CharEncoding.UTF8;
doc.Options.RawOut = true;
doc.Options.EncloseText = false;
```

and then change 
`doc.Options.CharEncoding = CharEncoding.UTF8;`
to `doc.Options.CharEncoding = CharEncoding.Raw;` but nothing happens.

Comment: can you tell how or what you have tried so far?

Comment: @parag-meshram, I added details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

In file Lexer.cs on line 371 number should be HEX.
I change it to

```
if (numeric && ((c == 'x') || (c == 'a') || (c == 'b') || (c == 'c') || (c == 'd') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'f') || (c == 'A') || (c == 'B') || (c == 'C') || (c == 'D') || (c == 'E') || (c == 'F')|| ((map & DIGIT) != 0)))
```

and parser become work properly.

Comment: Does anybody know how to commit this changes to Tidy.NET official?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Replace method of the System.String class to fix the broken HTML